# The meaning of API

Tags: java, api, data-transfer-objects

Could anyone please tell me the meaning of **API** in following paragraph, that's actually about **Transfer Object**:

> If it's likely that a business service
>   might be asked to send or receive all
>   or most of its data in a big,
>   coarse-grained message, it's common
>   for that service to provide that
>   feature in its **API**.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Google for it, really. First result.

Comment: bear in mind its really easy to google "wiki API"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"Application Programming Interface" - a set of functions that a programmer uses to communicate with a piece of software or a service.

Answer (score 3):

API = Application Programming Interface.  It is your formal statement of the programming interafce you offer to other components. If you are a serious service provider then you pay careful attention to the design of your API. The use of DTOs is often very appropriate in the provisision of a good interface.

[Wikipedia Link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface)

Answer (score 1):

> an application programming interface (API) is an interface that defines the ways by which an application program may request services from libraries and/or operating systems

see here:

[Wikipedia article on API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface)

Answer (score 0):

It just means that that the object exposes methods. It's not uncommon for people to use the term API when they means methods of an object.

Edit: By the way, API means Application Programmable Interface

Answer (score 0):

to add to the previous answers, let's say for the delicious websites API, in your current program, you can ask for it info on the last site that was bookmarked by a user to put it onto your website. In order to do that, delicious provides a url in their API, and you can use that with certain parameters and it will return you a html code...

Basically any sites/program that provides an API, basically enables the developers to use its database (dictated by them) and they basically provide methods to the developers in their API section

Answer (score 0):

When you talk about any object's "API", you're talking about the functions (aka 'commands') you can send to that object.

Answer (score 0):

API = application programming interface

The best way to compare a formal API is an contract between certain parts of your code.

If you call me in this certain way, I will always respond in that certain way.